# Within robot framework find an xpath within an element variable

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I have currently got a situation where I need to get all elements on a page, iterate through the elements 1 by 1 and within each element, I want to see if a certain other element exists.

To make it more clear, this is my loop:

```
${elements} =   Get WebElements  //li[@class='product-item--row js_item_root ']
FOR  ${item}  IN  @{elements}
    
    This is the part where I need to check within ${item} if the xpath exists: 
    //*[contains(text(), '${companyname}')]

END
```

So basically, I have 24 elements on my page which have the xpath

```
//li[@class='product-item--row js_item_root ']
```

I have 1 element on my page which can be located by xpath

```
//li[@class='product-item--row js_item_root ']//*[contains(text(), '${companyname}')]
```

And I want to know, within the 24 elements, which place the element is located which contains

```
//*[contains(text(), '${companyname}')]
```

Hoping someone can help!

**Edit**

This does not work:

```
Element should be visible  ${item}//*[contains(text(), 'BargainsKing')]
```

And that's because:

```
Element with locator '<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4b40581d8835aac628e3a2032e355ee5", element="663438f7-76eb-4801-b255-021a865035dd")>//*[contains(text(), 'BargainsKing')]' not found.
```

**Edit**

I found the

```
${item.get_attribute('innerHTML')}
```

Now my next/final question is, can I look up an xpath within this innerHTML?

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to count the number of elements and then get a FOR to cycle all elements

```
${count}    Get Element Count    XmlLocatorForAllElements
FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1        ${count}
    ${tmpElement}    Get Element Count    XmlLocator[${i}]/WithCompany
    IF    ${tmpElement} > ${0}
        #element found
    END
END
```

Comment: While this is true, and thanks for noting it, how will I get the xpath of that element? That's the main exit criterium. When I find my element, I want to interact with that element :-)

Comment: Ok I understand what you want. you need to get the element count and then cycle x times until you find the match. I'll edit the response

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide more detail about the selectors?
For now, I think you should try this:

- You can check in the selector if there are any incremental values
- if not then add a counter for each row
- for selecting a specific column you can either go with the counter or the company name in Xpath

Comment: I understand the concept of adding incremental values. So seeing which "number" it is won't be the issue. My question is more focussed on how to find an xpath within an element variable in robot framework